# WorksheetFunction.AverageIf of a range to include condition based on cell.interior.color

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, average, worksheet-function

I am trying to find the average of a column with undefined number (i) of values (range is likely to be between 3-20 cells in column I, row 24 up to undefined number - `j = 23 + i`). The code previously included only the standard average function.

Now, I'd like it to average those cells in the give range, only including those cells in the proposed range. Hence, ignoring the identified outliers that are above and/ or below LFe, UFe. Location of that averaged value is `Range("E" & m)`.

Is this even possible in the given worksheetfunction? And if so, what do I need to change to get this working?

I have tried to use existing solutions based on conditions such as 'average only cells that are positive' or 'only those that do not include N/A', but can't seem to get it working.

[image: example of data]

```
'Identifying outliers based on interquartile range
qe1 = Application.Quartile(Range("E24:E" & j), 1)
qe3 = Application.Quartile(Range("E24:E" & j), 3)
IQRe = qe3 - qe1
UFe = qe3 + (IQRe * 1.5)
LFe = qe3 - (IQRe * 1.5)

'[EDIT] Currently I have it as follows:
Range("E" & m).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(Range("E24:E" & j), "<" & UFe, Range("E24:E" & j), ">" & LFe, Range("E24:E" & j))
```

Which returns: #VALUE! without the .WorksheetFunction, and 'run error '424' Object required' as written above.

The only option that functioned, BUT not with my variable ranges is formatting it similarly as following: (How can this otherwise be adapted to work for my variable ranges, including 'j' etc.?)

```
Range("E" & m).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGEIF(R[-6]C[4]:R[-3]C[4],"">""& 4.3,R[-6]C[4]:R[-3]C[4])"
```

Comment: If the colour is based on a numerical criteria, use that in your average calculation.

Comment: I currently use the following: 
    Range("I" & m).Value = Application.AverageIf(Range("I24:I" & j), ">" & LFi, Range("I24:I" & j)), but it still returns me an issue, as the range contains one value lower than LFi, and it returns #DIV/0!  I'd like it to be an AverageIfs(Range("I24:I" & j), ">" & LFi, Range("I24:I" & j), "<" & UFi, Range("I24:I" & j)). If I'd put back in WorksheetFunction, than it will exit with run-time error '1004'.

Comment: If the issue is the DIV/0 then wrap it in IFERROR or add an If statement to your code.

Comment: So the following should work:    Range("E" & m).Value = Application.WorksheetsFunction.AverageIfs(Range("E24:E" & j), "<" & UFe, Range("E24:E" & j), ">" & LFe, Range("E24:E" & j))     , but here I now get the error '438': object doesn't support this property of method. Or if I remove the WorksheetFunction part, it returns #VALUE!.

Comment: Please can you add the code you've tried to your question? As you can see code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: edited my question, you are right, the cell color condition could be omitted. It just needs to follow the same condition as the cell coloring was based on (if above or below certain value, then color is defined). Now that it only needs to average those value that satisfy this condition.

Comment: What are the values of `UFe` and `LFe`? Seems to me that there might not be any overlap in which case there are no observations to average.

Comment: Ah, the syntax of AVERAGEIFS is different from AVERAGEIF - see Excel Help. You need average range, then your criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not enough rep to comment (sorry!), but here are a few ideas I had:

1) As SJR has mentioned, if there is a numeric value you're basing the color-coding from, you can use that in your code instead of a color. I'm thinking UFe & LFe are the upper and lower thresholds. So you could just have cells with formulas to automate the UFe & LFe via formulas instead and then use "AVERAGEIFS".

2) Alternatively, you could integrate your variables into a ".formula" instead, like:

```
Sheet1.Range("E" & m).Formula = "=AVERAGEIFS($E$24:$E$" & j & ",$E$24:$E$" & j & ","">" & LFe & """,$E$24:$E$" & j & ",""<" & UFe & """)"
```

Just change "Sheet1" to whatever sheet you're referencing

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to update the references in the "AVERAGEIFS" formula from my test workbook to match your references. I've updated my post to reference the range you're trying to review.

It could also be a result of none of the values meeting the criteria (i.e. all values are below LFe or above UFe; but hopefully it is just the problem noted above.

Comment: Checking the references; (yours was still an 'A' off), I think I have found the issue. In the module itself, it defines LFe and UFe as say 6,2222 instead of 6.2222, while my worksheet itself uses the seperators  '.' for decimal and ',' for thousands. Not sure how to solve that other than working in the system seperators. Such a stupid thing. :') Thanks!